# Genearlization of Spherical Coordinates in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to compute the integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{-(|x_1|^{p_1} + \cdots + |x_n|^{p_n})}\,dx_1\ldots \,dx_n
$$
in terms of the volume of the "unit ball"
$$
B_{p_1,\ldots, p_n} := \{x = (x_1,\ldots, x_n)\in\mathbb R^n: |x_1|^{p_1} + \cdots + |x_n|^{p_n}\leq 1\}.
$$
(My end goal is to prove the result shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball#Generalizations).)

My first instinct was to let
$$
E_r := \{x = (x_1,\ldots, x_n)\in\mathbb R^n: |x_1|^{p_1} + \cdots + |x_n|^{p_n} = r\}
$$
and mimic the standard use of spherical coordinates by writing the integral as
$$
\int_0^\infty \int_{E_r}e^{-r}\,dA\,dr = \int_0^\infty (r^{n-1}\operatorname{vol}(E_1))e^{-r}\,dr = \operatorname{vol}(E_1)\Gamma(n).
$$
(Here I'm using $\operatorname{vol}$ as a substitute for "surface area", since I don't know the standard notation for this.)  However, this already isn't correct: the factor $\Gamma(n)$ is independent of the values of $p_1$ through $p_n$, and furthermore this doesn't match the result one is supposed to get in the $p_1 = \cdots = p_n = 2$ case (namely $\tfrac12\Gamma(\tfrac n2)$).

It's clear that I'm missing something fundamental about how iterated integration works, but I'm not sure what it is nor how to fix it.  (I've also attempted to perform a change of variables and compute the Jacobian directly, but I'm not sure how to do this in a way that allows the integrand to be written only in terms of $r$.)

How would I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: My thought is that you want a volume form: "Volume element - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_element